# TypeScript error "Interface 'NodeBuffer' incorrectly extends interface 'Uint8Array'"

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

When I'm trying to compile my Angular application I get this error:

> ERROR in ...\src\page-sidebar\typings\browser\ambient\node\index.d.ts
>   (426,11): error TS2430: Interface 'NodeBuffer' incorrectly extends interface 'Uint8Array'.
>     Types of property 'fill' are incompatible.
>       Type '(value: any, offset?: number, end?: number) => Buffer' is not assignable to type '(value: number, start?: number, end?: number) => this'.
>         Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'this'.

My TypeScript and typings are updated to  latest versions:

```
"typescript": "2.1.6",
"typings": "2.1.0
```

Does anyone know where could be the problem?

Comment: The best thing to do with errors like this is to search for the text of the error online. I did, and found that, perhaps, reinstalling the node typings would help: https://www.garysieling.com/blog/fixing-typescript-error-error-ts2430-interface-nodebuffer-incorrectly-extends-interface-uint8array. Otherwise, you can log the error at https://github.com/types/env-node/issues.

Comment: In order to check what the problem is we need to see the code of index.d.ts

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the typing definitions for Node. Running `typings i env~node -SG` worked for me. I found the solution here https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/554

Hope it helps.

Comment: perfect answer !!